# Right Abbreviation for Length in garments

Tags: terminology, abbreviations

I am creating a form for web, and the word Length is being again and again e.g *Sleeve Length, Leg Length, Inner Leg Length*. Making everything a bit too long. According to [this](https://www.allacronyms.com/length/abbreviated) website, the *LEN* is used for telecom industry and doesn't say what abbreviation can be used for Length in garment business.

Comment: And, I suppose if you write *L'gth*, if you include the apostrophe, you only reduce it by one character. Can't you write *length" at the top, and use ditto marks?

Comment: L`gth isn't gonna be good i suppose, for the second option, can you depict or give me a example?

Comment: Clarity is more important, so keep "length" "length".

Comment: @NVZ yes but question is not about clarify. It is for the right abbreviation to use for word length

Comment: [Here are some abbreviations](http://www.abbreviations.com/abbreviation/length), though I'd echo @NVZ's note of caution. By the way, can you please add a link to the words "this website" in your question?

Comment: You could use a title for your list that includes "length" in a way that keeps you from reusing the word.

Comment: Personally, I don't see why *len* is not OK. An abbreviation is an abbreviation. But @NVZ is right that an abbreviation which does not obscure clarity is important; if there isn't one (and you feel *len* is inappropriate despite its use elsewhere) then it's best not to use one.

Comment: @Lawrence sorry  forgot to mention the ink. I have updated my question with link.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in @jejorda2's comment, if there is a common heading saying e.g. *Enter your measurements*, then *length* seems implicit, so the following should suffice:

> Sleeve
>   Leg
>   Inner Leg

Or maybe even:

> Sleeve (cm)
>   Leg (cm)
>   Inner Leg (cm)

By the way, you could use tooltips over each label for a 'wordier' version e.g. *"Length of ..."*.